Is there a way to have a shared document with someone else?
When I shared my project with a friend who wanted to contribute, he could make changes, but they did not appear in my version. For example, if you share a Word document, any changes made by the recipient will be reflected in your document as well. Is it possible to do so with Blender?

afaik there is no such functionality in Blender.

Ubisoft has created an addon called Mixer that allows you to share the same file. Here is demo video made by Gamefromscratch.
